# Loading a class if it is not already defined

Tags: php, cakephp

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7 (although also looking for non-CakePHP specific solution)*

Is it possible to check if a class is already defined and only load a specific library if that class is not yet defined?

**Example**

In my current project I have created a CakePHP plugin. This plugin uses several libraries that were made by myself or my colleagues. A colleague would like any libraries used by a plugin to be included in the plugin itself - so that updating an application to the latest plugin doesn't require updating any libraries inside the application.

Is it possible to check if a class has already been defined and only load the library inside the plugin if it hasn't? Otherwise conflicts arise from multiple definitions of a class.

I guess what I'm looking for is something to act like the PHP (or CakePHP specific) version of header guards in C++.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: Separate the libraries from the plugin, use proper namespaces, and head for composer.

Comment: @ndm How would you recommend handling a situation where plugin A needs version 1 of library Foo but plugin B needs version 2 of library Foo? This is my colleague's main argument against doing exactly what you just suggested (I have already namespaced the libraries, I don't know what you mean by "head for composer").

Comment: Follow the [**SemVer**](http://semver.org/) standard, update the plugins to use compatible versions, require compatible versions of the plugins, problem solved. By "_head for composer_" I mean, use [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage your apps dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @AbraCadaver's comment, using `class_exists` should do the trick

```
if (!class_exists('MyClass',false)){
    include 'MyClass.php';
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) This solves the problem. However, how would you solve the problem of 2 plugins in the same app both needing different versions of the same library?

Comment: You are welcome! For the second question I'm afraid I need more details. What do you mean by plugin, is it a class? what do you mean by a library and how is one version different from another? with full details I'm sure we can find a solution :)

Comment: Plugin in this sense is for the CakePHP framework - it's a whole bundle of classes but acts as a cohesive unit (such as an address manager plugin). A library could also be several classes (most so far are just one though). Different versions may differ by a small bug fix, or addition/deprecation of functionality - we are just beginning to implement proper version control. Does that help clarify?